# Aplicar CSS al primer elemento de tipo th que no sea oculto

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Tengo el siguiente problema: Necesito hacer que el border radius izquierdo del header de una tabla sea redondo en la parte izquierda.

En principio iba a hacerlo por CSS diciéndole que le aplicase el border radius al primer hijo, pero da la casualidad de que no me vale ya que el primer hijo es un th oculto, y yo necesito que se lo aplique al primer hijo que además sea visible. Lo mismo tengo que hacer con todos los tds que no estén ocultos. Investigando un poco he visto que en principio no es posible solo por CSS puro, y que lo ideal es recurrir a JQuery o JavaScript.

Agradecería una mano, me valdría una solución en cualquiera de ambos. A continuación reproduzco la estructura básica del HTML. Como aclaración previa diré que los ids son dinámicos:

```
<table class="mTabla" id="sdsdsdsf" style="margin: 0px auto; width: 100%; text-align: left; border-collapse: collapse;" border="1" rules="all" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <th style="display: none;" scope="col">#IdOculto</th>
        <th style="width: 200px;" scope="col">A1</th>
        <th style="width: 250px;" scope="col">A2</th>
        <th style="width: 200px;" scope="col">A3</th>

    </tr>
    <tr id="sdsdsds" style="cursor: pointer;">
        <td style="display: none;">57</td>
        <td>D1</td>
        <td>D1</td>
        <td>D1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="sdsdsds" style="cursor: pointer;">
        <td style="display: none;">58</td>
        <td>D2</td>
        <td>D2</td>
        <td>D2</td>
    </tr>       

    </tbody>
```

Comment: ¿Tienes la posibilidad de modificar el HTML que nos muestras? Si es así lo más sencillo sería tener una clase que tenga configurado el border-radius que necesitas y añadirle tú la clase a los th que te interesen. Me temo que de no ser así ya tendrías que recurrir a Jquery.

Comment: Ese es el tema, que no me dejan esa posibilidad

Answer (score 1):

Te escribo un selector de **Jquery** que conseguiría seleccionar tan solo los `<th>` que te interesan. Lo que hace es seleccionar el primer `<th>` que sea visible.

**JQUERY**

```
$('th:visible').first().css('color', 'red');
```

Le puse un cambio de color a rojo para que veas al `<th>` que está afectando el selector. Dentro ya le meterías tú los estilos que necesites para ese `<th>`.

Answer (score 0):

una manera muy sencilla es agregar en tu style:

```
border-top-left-radius: 40px;
```

Con esto redondeara la parte superior izquierda.

Otra manera en tu archivo CSS:

```
.mTabla{
    border-top-left-radius: 40px;
}
```

Comment: El problema es que me dejan la opción de manipular el HTML porque habría que retocar en todos los ficheros donde haya tablas, por eso me piden JQUERY o JS

Comment: Puedes hacerlo directamente con CSS agregas una clase que se llame .table-border{ border-top-left-radius: 40px; } y a la tabla solo agregas table class="table-border"

Comment: Hola. Me temo que no puedo manipularlo de esa forma, no porque no quiera o no se me haya ocurrido, sino porque no me dejan andar retocando todos los ficheros con HTML

Comment: Entonces con JQuery:

Comment: $("table").css("border-top-left-radius","40px");

Answer (score 0):

Podrias intentar quitar el style que tienes para la table y las opciones marcadas como border y rules y probar agregando en css, si es que los primeros hijos siempre van a ser ocultos.

```
table tr th:nth-child(2),td:nth-child(2) {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
th,td{
  border:1px solid black
}
```

Comment: El problema es que me dejan la opción de manipular el HTML porque habría que retocar en todos los ficheros donde haya tablas, por eso me piden JQUERY o JS

Comment: Puedes usar jquery para colocar el border-collapse a la propiedad initial y usar jquery para agrear esos estilos

Comment: $("th,td").css({
  'border':'1px solid black'
})
$('.mTabla').css({
  'border-collapse' : 'initial'
})
$(".mTabla tr th:nth-child(2),td:nth-child(2)").css({
  'border-top-left-radius': '20px',
})

Answer (score 0):

Si es posible seleccionar el primer elemento visible con CSS puro. Podés usar el selector `+`, que especifica el elemento inmediatamente adyacente al elemento especificado. De esta forma, el CSS queda así:

```css
.mTabla tbody tr td[style*='display'] + td{
    background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<table class="mTabla" id="sdsdsdsf" style="margin: 0px auto; width: 100%; text-align: left; border-collapse: collapse;" border="1" rules="all" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
      <tr>
          <th style="display: none;" scope="col">#IdOculto</th>
          <th style="width: 200px;" scope="col">A1</th>
          <th style="width: 250px;" scope="col">A2</th>
          <th style="width: 200px;" scope="col">A3</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr id="sdsdsds" style="cursor: pointer;">
          <td style="display: none;">57</td>
          <td>D1</td>
          <td>E1</td>
          <td>F1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="asdasd" style="cursor: pointer;">
          <td style="display: none;">58</td>
          <td>D2</td>
          <td>E2</td>
          <td>F2</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
```

La razón por la que `:nth-child()` y `:nth-of-type()` no funcionan es porque los `td` que están ocultos son, pues, del mismo tipo del elemento que queremos seleccionar, y sobreescribe la regla de estilo de un `:not()`. De esta forma, el selector `td:not([style*="display: none"]):first-child()` no funciona, dado que el elemento oculto **es** el `first-child` de la lista de `td`.

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer lo que tu quieres primero debes de remover el atributo `rules="all"` de tu tabla y la propiedad del estilo `border-collapse: collapse;`, por que? porque el agua no se puede mezclar con el aceite, es decir, si mandas a colapsar el border de la tabla no podrás visualizar dicho borde y en defecto de los coloca todo cuadrado y el `rules=all` esta deprecated, osea esta en desuso, luego puedes colocar la propiedad css que te puede dar ese efecto del border así:

```
.mTabla th:nth-child(2){
  border-top-left-radius:6px;
}
```

```css
.mTabla th, td{
  border:1px solid;
}

.mTabla th:nth-child(2){
  border-top-left-radius:6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="mTabla" id="sdsdsdsf" style="margin: 0px auto; width: 100%; text-align: left; " cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th style="display: none;" scope="col">#IdOculto</th>
      <th style="width: 200px;" scope="col">A1</th>
      <th style="width: 250px;" scope="col">A2</th>
      <th style="width: 200px;" scope="col">A3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="sdsdsds" style="cursor: pointer;">
        <td style="display: none;">57</td>
        <td>D1</td>
        <td>D1</td>
        <td>D1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="sdsdsds" style="cursor: pointer;">
        <td style="display: none;">58</td>
        <td>D2</td>
        <td>D2</td>
        <td>D2</td>
    </tr>   
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Con jquery:**

```js
$('th:visible').first().css('border-top-left-radius', '6px');
```

```css
.mTabla th, td{
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <table class="mTabla" id="sdsdsdsf" style="margin: 0px auto; width: 100%; text-align: left; " cellspacing="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th style="display: none;" scope="col">#IdOculto</th>
          <th style="width: 200px;" scope="col">A1</th>
          <th style="width: 250px;" scope="col">A2</th>
          <th style="width: 200px;" scope="col">A3</th>
        </tr>
        <tr id="sdsdsds" style="cursor: pointer;">
            <td style="display: none;">57</td>
            <td>D1</td>
            <td>D1</td>
            <td>D1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="sdsdsds" style="cursor: pointer;">
            <td style="display: none;">58</td>
            <td>D2</td>
            <td>D2</td>
            <td>D2</td>
        </tr>   
      </tbody>
    </table>
```